# Build error for orml_xtokens

Tags: error, build, orml-xtokens

I have recently upgraded our blockchain to use polkadot-v0.9.26 but when I am building the code I get the following

```
error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/aibrayanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d1f2e33a8ae5e2c9/33dbc5e/xtokens/src/lib.rs:900:39
    |
900 |                         ToReserve | ToNonReserve => Xcm(vec![
    |                                                         ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/aibrayanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d1f2e33a8ae5e2c9/33dbc5e/xtokens/src/lib.rs:895:31
    |
895 |                         SelfReserveAsset => Xcm(vec![TransferReserveAsset {
    |                                                 ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/aibrayanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d1f2e33a8ae5e2c9/33dbc5e/xtokens/src/lib.rs:837:39
    |
837 |                         ToReserve | ToNonReserve => Xcm(vec![
    |                                                         ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/aibrayanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d1f2e33a8ae5e2c9/33dbc5e/xtokens/src/lib.rs:832:31
    |
832 |                         SelfReserveAsset => Xcm(vec![TransferReserveAsset {
    |                                                 ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/aibrayanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d1f2e33a8ae5e2c9/33dbc5e/xtokens/src/lib.rs:740:12
    |
740 |                 Ok(Xcm(vec![
    |                        ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/aibrayanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d1f2e33a8ae5e2c9/33dbc5e/xtokens/src/lib.rs:720:12
    |
720 |                 Ok(Xcm(vec![
    |                        ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/aibrayanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d1f2e33a8ae5e2c9/33dbc5e/xtokens/src/lib.rs:684:11
    |
684 |             Ok(Xcm(vec![
    |                    ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/aibrayanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d1f2e33a8ae5e2c9/33dbc5e/xtokens/src/lib.rs:667:11
    |
667 |             Ok(Xcm(vec![TransferReserveAsset {
    |                    ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/aibrayanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d1f2e33a8ae5e2c9/33dbc5e/xtokens/src/lib.rs:438:39
    |
438 |             Self::do_transfer_multiassets(who, vec![asset.clone()].into(), asset, dest, dest_weight)
    |                                                ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /home/aibrayanov/.cargo/git/checkouts/open-runtime-module-library-d1f2e33a8ae5e2c9/33dbc5e/xtokens/src/lib.rs:400:39
    |
400 |             Self::do_transfer_multiassets(who, vec![asset.clone()].into(), asset, dest, dest_weight)
    |                                                ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec
```

for `orml-xtokens` . I have tried to import all of the suggested items but still get the same error. Any idea how I can fix this? You can find the code [here](https://github.com/chexware/Bit-Country-Blockchain/tree/runtime-upgrade/polkadot-v0.9.26)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed something like `orml-xtokens/std` in the `Cargo.toml`.